# Liferay Asset Publisher full content

Tags: liferay-6

I'm using Liferay for the first time at work and I'm facing the following issue: I have an Asset Publisher which lists some web contents (abstracts). I want to see full content in another page when clicking one of the content items in the asset publisher. I believe this is a very common functionality but still haven´t been able to find a solution (hopefully it is quite simple). I'm using Liferay CE 6.2 GA5.

Answer (score 1):

From the "Asset Link Behavior" drop down in the Asset Publisher configuration settings (get there by clicking the gear icon on the top right of your AP, choose "Configuration", then click on "Display Settings" tab) you can choose "View in Context". This should allow your content to open in a separate page.

You will also need to set a "Display Page" for your Web content (abstracts). Create the page where you want to display the full content, add an Asset Publisher to that page, and configure that asset publisher to "Set as the Default Asset Publisher for This Page" and "Show only assets with 'your chosen page name' as its display page." - these are checkboxes in the configuration settings.

Here's the documentation from Liferay: https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-the-asset-publisher

I hope this helps.